# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance how can I fix

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am having error like this in my project:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Invalid attempt to spread
> non-iterable instance. In order to be iterable, non-array objects must
> have a Symbol.iterator method

Here is my SortContracts.ts code:

```
function sortContracts(
  contracts: ContractUsage[],
  sortField?: SortType,
  sortDirection?: SortDirection
): any[] {
  let sortFunction:any
  switch (sortField) {
    // Sort by End Date
    case SortType.DATE_SORT:
      if (sortDirection === SortDirection.ASC) {
        // Sort by End Date ASC
        sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => endDateSortAscFunc(a, b);
      } else {
        // Sort by End Date DESC
        sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => endDateSortDescFunc(a, b);
      }
      break;

    // Sort by ContractID
    case SortType.CONTRACT_SORT:
      if (sortDirection === SortDirection.ASC) {
        // Sort by ContractID ASC
        sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => contractIdSortAscFunc(a, b);
      } else {
        // Sort by ContractID DESC
        sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => contractIdSortDescFunc(a, b);
      }
      break;

    case SortType.USAGE_ORDER:
      if (sortDirection === SortDirection.ASC) {
        sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => usageOrderSortAscFunc(a, b);
      } else {
        sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => usageOrderSortDescFunc(a, b);
      }
      break;
    // default sort
    default:
      sortFunction = (a:any, b:any) => contractIdSortAscFunc(a, b);
  }

  // Return the sorted contracts
  console.log('contract here: ',  [...contracts].sort(sortFunction))
  return [...contracts].sort(sortFunction);
}
```

[image]

Comment: It says that contracts is not itereable i.e. it is not an array. You need to know what is contracts, just debug it and see which type of object it is.

Comment: The most likely cause for this is that `contracts` is initially `null`, as opposed to an empty array `[]`

Answer (score 1):

The variable you are trying to spread (ie. `[...contracts]`) is not [iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/iterator). If you want use this operator, [you need to have this variable iterable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#only_for_iterables). **Check the variable if it is really an array (or any other iterable type) and if it's not null or undefined**.